# OneDrive for Business File Read/Write with Application Permission already supported?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, office365, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

I would like my app to access (read/write) Onedrive files of a specific Office-Account with Application Permission only (to be clear: not a delegated permission). documentation is very sketchy about this. Is this is even currently supported? I read a post form 2016 which stated it was not at that time.

I am using Microsoft Graph as the API, A web-app based on .Net Core 2.2 and VS2019 as the IDE.
The app is properly registered in Azure Active Directory with application permissions for files read/write

My App is able to:

- To get an Access Token
- To read Sharepoint Sites
  (`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drive/root/children`)
- I cannot
  read/write the Onedrive files however
  (`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root/children`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this scenario is supported. Note above you used `v1.0/me` but "me" doesn't mean anything in application context since the requests aren't made on behalf of a user. Try using /users/{id or user principal name}/drive/etc instead. If this doesn't help please update your post with the failed request id, timestamp and the exact error response. Request id is available in response headers from Graph.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. the `/me/` I copied from the Microsoft Graph Explorer. I will experiment with your suggestion and see what happens.